# Autowire all interfaces keyed by type

Tags: spring, java-8

I've a an interface and there are multiple implementations of the interface. There can be only one type of implementation for each interface type and I want to collect all the interface implementations per type, i.e.

```
Map<String, InterfaceExample>

public interface InterfaceExample {
    String getType();
    ClassA getClassA();
}
```

If I had to get in this form `Map<String, List<InterfaceExample>>` I would have done in the following way:

```
@Autowired
private List<InterfaceExample> interfaceExamples;

@Bean
public Map<String, List<IntefaceExample>> getExamples() {
    return interfaceExamples.stream()
            .map(x -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x.getType(), x))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Now that I've to ensure there is only one implementation per type I can do in following way:

```
@Bean
public Map<String, IntefaceExample> getExamples() {
    Map<String, List<IntefaceExample>> examples = interfaceExamples.stream()
            .map(x -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x.getType(), x))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));

    Map<String, InterfaceExample> output = new HashMap<>();
    examples.forEach((key, value) -> {
        if(value.size() > 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Wrongly configured!! ");
        } else if(value.size() == 1) {
            output.put(key, value.get(0));
        }
    });
    return output;
}
```

Is there a different way to ensure that there is only implementation per type and create the bean in a "streamified way" without explicitly creating the output map?

Answer (score 1):

After groupingby you can check if there are multiple beans of same type and collect them into `List`

```
List<InterfaceExample> res = interfaceExamples.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(InterfaceExample::getType)).values()
            .stream().map(value -> {
                if (value.size() == 1) {
                    return value.get(0);
                }
                throw new RuntimeException("Wrongly configured!! ");
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The best way is write a custom method that does the validation logic

```
public InterfaceExample conditionCheck(List<InterfaceExample> value) {
    if (value.size() == 1) {
        return value.get(0);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Wrongly configured!! ");
}
```

And then simply use `stream`

```
List<InterfaceExample> res = interfaceExamples.stream()
                                              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(InterfaceExample::getType))
                                              .values()
                                              .stream()
                                              .map(this::conditionCheck)
                                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```